# Product of the elements of the group $n$th power of $G$ is identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with identity element $e$. Suppose that $\#G = n$ and $(a_{1},....,a_{n})\in G^{n}= G\times\dots G$ ($n$-times). To prove : There exists $r$,$s$ with $0 \leq r<s\leq n$ such that $a_{r+1}\cdot\dots a_{s} = e$

I am aware of the properties which qualify a set to a group.I can make out that the ordered pair $(a_{1},....,a_{n})$ will be different combinations of the elements of group $G$, their inverses in $G$ and the identity element of $G$. But I cannot make out how all the elements in ANY of all the combinations of the ordered pairs when multiplied together will yield the identity element.I hope my comprehension of the problem is correct. I am totally new to this subject. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $a_1$, $a_1a_2$, $a_1a_2a_3$, and so on up to $a_1a_2\cdots a_n$. If one of these is equal to the identity element, we are finished.

If none of them is equal to the identity element, then since the group has $n$ elements, by the Pigeonhole Principle two of the products $a_1a_2\cdots a_r$ and $a_1a_2\cdots a_r\cdots a_s$ are equal. Multiply both on the left by $a_1^{-1}$, then by $a_2^{-1}$, and so on up to $a_r^{-1}$, and we get the desired result.

Comment: If I have understood cartesian product correctly then there can be one of the combination $(a_{1},e,e.....e)$ $(n-1)$ times $e$ then how can the product be identity.

Comment: @rotating_image:  The group structure of the Cartesian product has nothing to do with the problem. The problem only specifies that $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is an ordered $n$-tuple of group elements. It is therefore technically an element of the Cartesian product, but the action takes place entirely in $G$.

Comment: Got it...thank you...one last favor...plz suggest me some reference book/books where applications and problems of this kind are dealt with. I have browsed some random group theory books...but having less of problem solving.

Comment: @rotating_image: I have no useful book suggestion. This particular problem is really a combinatorial problem, with the group stuff playing a minor role.